# getter method vs directly using input param

Tags: java, eclipse

I have come across this code (simplified of course) in the project I have been assigned to.

**Method Option 1**

```
public myType getSomething(final int pTeamId) {
    this.teamId = pTeamId;
    final ClassABC classABC = new ClassABC(pTeamId);
    ...
    return myType;
}
```

Notice how the input parameter `pTeamId` is being assigned to the private data member `teamId` in the first line of the method.  Please note that there are getter and setter methods for this `teamId` data member (Which I have not bothered to include for simplicity's sake.  Just know they are a standard getter/setter pair).

So I suppose I could write this method differently where I call the getter of the data member I just set instead of using the input parameter passed in directly as in Method Option 1:

**Method Option 2**

```
public myType getSomething(final int pTeamId) {
    this.teamId = pTeamId;
    final ClassABC classABC = new ClassABC(this.getTeamId());
    ...
    return myType;
}
```

I realize this question may seem trivial and/or stupid to some, but I am encountering this situation frequently in a large code base I am modifying, so I am curious about which is the "correct" way to approach this, Method option 1 or Method option 2.

I came across this thread, but it targets JavaScript: [speed of getter function vs direct access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838514/speed-of-getter-function-vs-direct-access)

My first inclination is to use Method Option 1, but I really do not have a good reason why, besides that "it looks *faster*...".

Can someone else provide a better reason(s)?

Specifically,

1) Is there is a proper/preferred convention/technique/practice in this scenario?

and

2) **WHY** is one option better than the other? Are they equal? Are there performance issues? etc.

Are there questions I am not asking? (or is this all an over-analysis)?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if some one overrides `getTeamId`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer...That sounds like a problem that had not even crossed my mind :P

Comment: is there still an open point or is every thing clear?

Comment: @PhilippSander Everything is clear.  I gave it a day to see if any other answers would be provided.  Yours was a sufficient explanation, however.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The getter could have logic in it like not returning `null` but an empty string instead.
same with the setter.

when you manipulate the variable directly you don't execute that logic.

this can also be a problem if someone overrides the getter and setter logic. (you can forbidd this by making them final) but this is not a common doing! (i would go one step further and call it an anti-pattern)

i would suggest always calling the getters/setters. and there is no real performance loss

Comment: +1, but that said, if the class is `final` (or if the getter is `final`) and the getter's implementation is simply `return teamId`, it's fine to access the field directly. I usually don't worry about encapsulation much _within_ a class. In fact, if I start worrying about encapsulation within a class, that's often a sign that the class is trying to do much.